# Dynamic Array equivalent

Tags: grails

Is there any dynamic array type variable in grails? At the moment I am just reverting to java and using a Vector but I want to try and keep the code as close to grails as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def dynamicArray = []
dynamicArray << anyObject
```

Technically if will not be an array, but a `List` of some sort, but it will give you a feel of array. More info is available in the javadocs [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections)

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but what does the bottom line do exactly?

Comment: it appends an object to the end of the collection.

Comment: bottom line is a equivalent of dynamicArry.put(anyObject)

Comment: Thanks, just trying it now!